# php.ini not updating on MacOS Sierra despite editing loaded configuration file from phpinfo() and php --ini

Tags: php, macos, apache, macos-sierra

I'm trying to update `memory_limit` in my `php.ini` file. This is what I've done so far (**this is php7 and I have no idea why it says php5**):

1. Created `phpinfo.php` file with just `phpinfo()` inside and opened it in my browser:

> PHP Version 7.0.12
>
> Configuration File (php.ini)       Path   /usr/local/php5/lib
>
> Loaded Configuration File /usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini
>
> Scan this dir for additional .ini files   /usr/local/php5/php.d

2. In the Terminal, I checked `php --ini` command:

> Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/php5/lib
>
> Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini
>
> Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/php5/php.d
>
> Additional .ini files parsed:      /usr/local/php5/php.d/10-extension_dir.ini

3. Once both ways determined `/usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini` as the loaded configuration file, I've made changes to it and then called `sudo apachectl restart` to apply the changes. That had absolutely zero effect on both command line PHP and the `phpinfo()` file.
4. This is where things get weird: as you've seen, the PHP used by phpinfo() is php 7.0.12, but when i execute `ls -la /usr/local | grep php` this is the output:

> lrwxr-xr-x    1 root           wheel    38 16 lis  2016 php5 -> /usr/local/php5-7.0.12-20161101-102255
>
> drwxr-xr-x   14 root           wheel   476 16 lis  2016 php5-5.6.27-20161101-100213
>
> drwxr-xr-x   14 root           wheel   476 16 lis  2016 php5-7.0.12-20161101-102255

So as you can see, something weird is going on and I have no idea how to properly update my php.ini. I've even tried making an additional .ini file in the directory scanned by php for additional .ini files and putting `memory_limit` there, but it had no effect. Does anyone know the solution to my problem?

Comment: yes, i've restarted it several times

Comment: Are there any files in `/usr/local/php5/php.d` that set the `memory_limit` value? They'll override whatever's set in the general `php.ini`. Also, try `which php` in a terminal to find out which binary is actually called. It's usually in a `bin` folder and not straight from the `/usr/local` folder.

Comment: @rickdenhaan there are two files with memory_limit, both set to 512M (thats what I want php to be) but they're not working. which php returns /usr/local/php5/bin/php

Comment: Alright, and if you call `php -i | grep memory_limit` and check the `phpinfo()` page, what do they report for `memory_limit`?

Comment: @rickdenhaan **php -i | grep memory_limit** now returns `memory_limit => 512M => 512M` but phpinfo() still says that memory_limit is 256M both local value and master value

Comment: Hmm, so it works for cli but not for apache. The only thing I can think of right now is that there's a `.htaccess` file or apache-config overriding it (maybe a `<VirtualHost>`, `<Location>`, `<Directory>` or `<DirectoryMatch>` entry) with a `php_value` parameter.